# Razor Page show spinner on while waiting for OnGetAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, spinner, razor-pages

I am trying to show a spinner while my `OnGetAsync` is processing.

I have a form that looks something like this:

```
<form method="get">
    <div class="row">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="action" value="1">1</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="action" value="2">2</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I have been able to show my spinner when pressing a button by adding an onclick that triggers the jquery .show() method. However, I then have no good way to stop it when my `OnGetAsync` returns.

What is the correct way to handle something like this?

---

Updated example:

```
<form method="get">
    <div class="row">
        <button id="pdfbutton" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="action" value="PDF">PDF</button> *@
        <span id="spinner" class="loader" style="display:none;"></span>
    </div>
</form>


@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $("#pdfbutton").click(function(){
            $("#spinner").show();
        });
    </script>
}

public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string? action)
    {
        if (action == "PDF") {
            var file = await File.ReadAllBytesAsync(<path to some pdf file>);
            return File(file, "application/pdf", "file.pdf");
        }
        return Page();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Chris, I found [another workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77645939/14574199) recently which I think is also a good option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in razor project, c# can't run in the client, here's another [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51314978) which mentioned it, so we'd better to control the loading to display or not. Since you didn't provide a minimal sample, so I have a test in my side with code  below:

```
<form method="get">
    <div class="row">
        @* <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="action" value="1">1</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="action" value="2">2</button> *@
        <button id="showImg">show loading</button>
    </div>
</form>

<div id="loadImg" style="display:none;">
    <img style="width:50px;height:50px;" src="~/loading.gif" />
</div>

@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $("#showImg").click(function(){
            $("#loadImg").show();
        });
    </script>
}

public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        return Page();
    }
}
```

And here's the test result.

[image]

Since I had a `return Page()` in the method, each time the `onGet` is called, the whole page would reload so that my loading icon would become the default invisible. If we want to reload part of the page like what ajax does, then all these should be controlled by js. For example, in the onclick event, we might send an ajax request, before sending the request, we could call the `.show()` method to display the loading icon, and inside the callback method, we could call `.hide()` method make it invisible.

===================   UPDATE   =================

The problem we are facing now it find a trigger to let the page know the form submission is completed, and we don't have such a callback method indeed, so I found a workaround which worked in this scenario.

```
$([window, top.window]).blur(function () {
    $("#loadImg").hide();
});
```

[image]

By the way, I tried to return File along with the page so that the page would reload and hide the loading icon, but it proved to be impossible. I also tried to define a variable but razor pages is not like razor component so that we couldn't monitor the variable to check if the submission is completed. Another way I think could be possible is that we submit the form/download the file via javascript manually so that we could control the icon to show or not in the file-download progress. For example, we can have code like this， this makes us not able to hide the icon whenever the file returned, but I trust if we are always trying to return a small file, then 1~2 seconds is enough.

```
$("#showImg2").click(function(){
    $("#loadImg").show();
    downloadUrl("/?action=PDF");
    setTimeout(hideImg, 2000);
});

function hideImg() { 
    $("#loadImg").hide();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Pls correct me if I misunderstood your requirement...

Comment: Thank you for the very in depth response. This is almost the behavior I want. The issue is that my `OnGetAsync` method only returns `Page()` in very rare occasions. Most of the time it returns a file that is then downloaded through the browser. When I return the file the page isnt "reloaded" and therefore the spinner remains spinning.

Comment: @Chris could you pls add some more codes so that I could further investigate your issue and maybe find a workaround?

Comment: I updated the original post with a new example. If I get to the `OnGetAsync` and `action` is not `"PDF"` the spinner stops as expected. But if `actions == "PDF"` and a file is returned the spinner never stops.

Comment: @Chris I updated in my post, I shared 2 workarounds, because I failed to find a form-submit-callback method for the file downloading.

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked! Do you mind explaining how/why it works? Does it look trigger when a download occurs?

Comment: I also just found that if I click my browser when the download window is open, and I press the button again the spinner remains even after the file is downloaded. Do you have an idea for fixing that?

Comment: `$([window, top.window]).blur` is triggerred when the downloading menu appeared, I mean, normally a popup would show in the right top of the browser to show the download process, when the popup appeared, then the browser is "blur" so that the event would be triggered. So it's just a workaround but not a solution. There must be some accident that couldn't hide the loading icon. So that's why I shared the second workaround...